# Search in array field elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search as my search engine for my app and i need search an value in array field. I tried look at the documentation but didn't succeed for can do this.

how i can do this ?

Comment: Show a sample document and specify what you want to search?

Comment: {
 "name" : "John",
 "musics" : [{
    "title" : "Dear Marie"
  }]
}

Comment: You want to search 'title' ???

Comment: Please share the mapping of your index??? `GET /index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mandado/25ce32bfc0dd27257457

Comment: I can't see musics and title field in the mapping mentioned by you ..